# Pass id from child component to parent component in react

Tags: reactjs

I have two js files, the structure is like

App.js ---> Booking.js

I have two textarea in bookings.js and I want to pass the id from bookings to app and manipulate my data in App.js, here is the code below

App.js

```
        import React, { Component } from "react";
        import Bookings from "./components/Bookings";
        import Meals from "./components/Meals";
        import Error from "./components/Error";

        Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
        var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
        return date;
        };

        class App extends Component {
        constructor() {
            super();
            this.state = {
            hackers: "",
            dateRange: "",
            error: false,
            errorMessage: [],
            schedule: []
            };
        }
        handleGuestInfo = event => {
            const { id, value } = event.currentTarget;
            this.setState({
            [id]: value
            });
        };

        handleDateInfo = event => {
            const { id, value } = event.currentTarget;
            this.setState({
            [id]: value
            });
        };

        dateFormatCheck(date) {
            let dateChecker = /^(?:(19|20)[0-9]{2})[-.](0[1-9]|1[012])[-.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/; //YYYY/MM-DD format
            if (
            dateChecker.test(date.split("to")[0]) &&
            dateChecker.test(date.split("to")[1])
            ) {
            return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        reset() {
            this.setState({
            error: false,
            errorMessage: "",
            errorData: [],
            schedule: []
            });
        }

        handleMealSchedule() {
            //this.reset();
            let hackers = this.state.hackers.split("\n");
            let dateRange = this.state.dateRange.split("\n");
            let errorData = [];
            let scheduleData = [];
            if (hackers.length === dateRange.length) {
            for (let i = 0; i < hackers.length; i++) {
                if (this.dateFormatCheck(dateRange[i])) {
                let startDay = dateRange[i].split("to")[0];
                let endDay = dateRange[i].split("to")[1];

                let noOfDays = this.getDifferenceInDays(startDay, endDay);
                for (let j = 0; j < noOfDays.length; j++) {
                    scheduleData.push(
                    "Breakfast for " + hackers[i] + " on " + noOfDays[j]
                    );
                    scheduleData.push("Lunch for " + hackers[i] + " on " + noOfDays[j]);
                    scheduleData.push(
                    "Dinner for " + hackers[i] + " on " + noOfDays[j]
                    );
                }
                } else {
                errorData.push("Meal data not available for " + hackers[i]);
                }
            }
            } else {
            errorData.push("Hackers and Date Range length mismatch");
            }

            if (errorData.length > 0) {
            this.setState({
                error: true,
                errorMessage: errorData
            });
            }
            this.setState({
            schedule: scheduleData
            });
        }

        getDifferenceInDays(startDate, endDate) {
            let dateArray = [];
            let currentDate = new Date(startDate);
            while (currentDate <= new Date(endDate)) {
            dateArray.push(new Date(currentDate).toLocaleDateString());
            currentDate = currentDate.addDays(1);
            }
            return dateArray;
        }
        render() {
            const { error, errorMessage, schedule } = this.state;

            return (
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <center>
                <h2>Hacker Hostel</h2>
                </center>
                <div className="container">
                <Bookings
                    onHackerChange={e => this.handleGuestInfo(e)}
                    onDateChange={e => this.handleDateInfo(e)}
                    onButton={this.handleMealSchedule}
                    hackerid={this.state.hackers}
                    daterangeid={this.state.dateRange}
                />
                {error ? <Error errorMessage={errorMessage} /> : null}
                {/* <Meals /> */}
                </div>
            </div>
            );
        }
        }

        export default App;
```

Booking.js

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";

    import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
    import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

    class Bookings extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
        <div className="row">
            <TextField
            className="col-md-6"
            multiline
            rows="4"
            id={this.props.hackerid}
            placeholder="Enter the hacker list (one hacker per line)"
            onChange={this.props.onHackerChange}
            />
            <TextField
            className="col-md-6"
            multiline
            rows="4"
            id={this.props.daterangeid}
            onChange={this.props.onDateChange}
            placeholder="Enter the date range for each hacker's stay (one range per line)"
            />
            <Button
            variant="outlined"
            color="primary"
            className="block-center"
            onClick={this.props.onButton}
            >
            Get Meals Schedule
            </Button>
        </div>
        );
    }
    }

    export default Bookings;
```

Any idea on how to do this ? The two textarea id is to be passed from bookings to app.js where all my validations have to be done.

Comment: see [Thinking in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html)

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? I don't see any validation in app.js that would need an `id` of a textarea. please update your question [to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to control  TextField values by using state in App and pass them to Booking component as props. Wouldnt need id too.

In App component,  you can use onChange function to update State value like:

```
  handleDateInfo = event => {
        const { id, value } = event.currentTarget;
        this.setState({
         DateRangeValue: value
        });
    };
```

And in bookings components, it will be something like this:

```
<TextField
        className="col-md-6"
        multiline
        rows="4"
        value={this.props.DateRangeValue}
        onChange={this.props.onDateChange}
        placeholder="Enter the date range for each hacker's stay (one range per line)"
        />
```

Also just to highlight from @Aprillion's comment, this will make TextFields [controlled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components).  You can read more about those in the link. In short, It makes state as the source value for the text field. To update text field values, you would also have to update it in state too.

Comment: FTR: this approach would introduce [Controlled Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) (not related to downvotes, just a comment)

Comment: `would introduce controlled components`.   Is introducing controlled components Bad ?

Comment: not bad if you know that you are doing. but the question does not look like it's safe to assume OP knows the implications of switching from uncontrolled to controlled components, so I added the link for anyone who was not aware of the significance of adding `value` to an `<input />`

Comment: ^ I see,  I will add this in my answer.